# What are the required steps to remove crimson.jar from an application?

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I'm facing several issues because of the presence of the crimson jar and most forum post the solution for this type of issues is to get rid of it.

**for example:**

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No attributes are
>   implemented
>       at org.apache.crimson.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.setAttribute(DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.java:93)

and the solution posted was:

> I would suggest using the current JAXP or the latest jdk which
>   includes jaxp 1.4 if you're just trying to get started with xml. JAXP
>   has replaced the Crimson parser since version 1.3. Refer to the 1.3
>   release notes https://jaxp.java.net/1.3/ReleaseNotes.html

But when I removed this **crimson.jar** I started facing problems everywhere like:

```
Jan 22, 2013 8:26:07 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester warning
WARNING: Parse Warning Error at line 1 column 0: URI was not reported to parser for entity [document]
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: URI was not reported to parser for entity [document]
    at gnu.xml.aelfred2.SAXDriver.warn(SAXDriver.java:934)
    at gnu.xml.aelfred2.SAXDriver.startExternalEntity(SAXDriver.java:631)
    at gnu.xml.aelfred2.XmlParser.pushURL(XmlParser.java:3358)
    at gnu.xml.aelfred2.XmlParser.doParse(XmlParser.java:159)
    at gnu.xml.aelfred2.SAXDriver.parse(SAXDriver.java:320)
    at gnu.xml.aelfred2.XmlReader.parse(XmlReader.java:294)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1543)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.tldScanStream(TldConfig.java:553)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.tldScanWebXml(TldConfig.java:383)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.execute(TldConfig.java:299)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.lifecycleEvent(TldConfig.java:585)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5061)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:812)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:787)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:607)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1360)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:297)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:761)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1406)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:832)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:347)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:591)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:394)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Jan 22, 2013 8:26:07 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester warning
WARNING: Parse Warning Error at line 3 column 138: No base URI; hope URI is absolute: http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-jsptaglibrary_1_1.dtd
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: No base URI; hope URI is absolute: http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-jsptaglibrary_1_1.dtd
    at gnu.xml.aelfred2.SAXDriver.warn(SAXDriver.java:934)
    at gnu.xml.aelfred2.XmlParser.readExternalIds(XmlParser.java:2399)
    at gnu.xml.aelfred2.XmlParser.parseDoctypedecl(XmlParser.java:804)
    at gnu.xml.aelfred2.XmlParser.parseProlog(XmlParser.java:522)
    at gnu.xml.aelfred2.XmlParser.parseDocument(XmlParser.java:414)
    at gnu.xml.aelfred2.XmlParser.doParse(XmlParser.java:167)
    at gnu.xml.aelfred2.SAXDriver.parse(SAXDriver.java:320)
    at gnu.xml.aelfred2.XmlReader.parse(XmlReader.java:294)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1543)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.tldScanStream(TldConfig.java:553)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.tldScanWebXml(TldConfig.java:383)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.execute(TldConfig.java:299)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.lifecycleEvent(TldConfig.java:585)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5061)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:812)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:787)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:607)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1360)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:297)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:761)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1406)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:832)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:347)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:591)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:394)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Jan 22, 2013 8:26:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester warning
WARNING: Parse Warning Error at line 3 column 140: No base URI; hope this SYSTEM id is absolute: http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-jsptaglibrary_1_1.dtd
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: No base URI; hope this SYSTEM id is absolute: http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-jsptaglibrary_1_1.dtd
    at gnu.xml.aelfred2.SAXDriver.warn(SAXDriver.java:934)
    at gnu.xml.aelfred2.SAXDriver.absolutize(SAXDriver.java:606)
    at gnu.xml.aelfred2.SAXDriver.resolveEntity(SAXDriver.java:585)
    at gnu.xml.aelfred2.XmlParser.pushURL(XmlParser.java:3336)
    at gnu.xml.aelfred2.XmlParser.parseDoctypedecl(XmlParser.java:845)
    at gnu.xml.aelfred2.XmlParser.parseProlog(XmlParser.java:522)
    at gnu.xml.aelfred2.XmlParser.parseDocument(XmlParser.java:414)
    at gnu.xml.aelfred2.XmlParser.doParse(XmlParser.java:167)
    at gnu.xml.aelfred2.SAXDriver.parse(SAXDriver.java:320)
    at gnu.xml.aelfred2.XmlReader.parse(XmlReader.java:294)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1543)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.tldScanStream(TldConfig.java:553)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.tldScanWebXml(TldConfig.java:383)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.execute(TldConfig.java:299)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.lifecycleEvent(TldConfig.java:585)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5061)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:812)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:787)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:607)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1360)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:297)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:761)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1406)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:832)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:347)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:591)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:394)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Jan 22, 2013 8:26:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.XmlErrorHandler logFindings
```

Some mentioned to use the jaxp 1.4 jar, others mentioned that xerces is the replacement for the crimson.jar. I have used both but I'm still getting those warning exceptions.

So my question is: what are the required steps to remove/replace this jar and/or any related jars from my application?

Comment: Is this an application you are developing, and if so, what build system do you use?  Ant?  Maven?  or is this just some binary deployable archive you obtained and deployed into your tomcat server?

Comment: I'm uisng Netbeans 7 (Ant)
I have an existing Web-Application that is using crimson.jar and currnetly I have to add module that do signinig, encryption, decryption, .. bla bla
the new module tested as stand alone app works fine after integrating into my web-app it throws this exception

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No attributes are implemented at org.apache.crimson.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.setAttribute(DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.java:93)

and when I tried to remove this crimson.jar I got the above mention long warning exception.

Comment: I am experiencing a similar problem. I am unable to launch a very old (but still necessary) application. If I try to launch it with anything more recent than java 1.4 I obtain this error message: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.crimson.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per http://xml.apache.org/crimson/ web page

2010/08/06 - Apache Crimson has been retired.

and The Crimson codebase is based on the Sun Project X parser. It is also the parser currently shipping in Sun products; however, the future plan is to move to a different codebase called Xerces Java 2. Xerces 2 is currently under development. [Link to Xerces 2, once a project page has been created.]

so Xerces is all what is needed but the problem is where xerces library should be placed if it is placed as part of your war it will generate all the problems raised above instead it should not be part of your war libraries it should be part of the Server shared libraries

for tomcat you can placed it in the lib folder for Websphere you can place it anywhere and add it to your application shared libraries classpath.

Comment: It has been retired, good, but it still appears in my stack traces.  It is not in any of my jars, not in any jar deployed on the server, not in the classes directory but it still shows up in my stack trace.